# minuit gives cryptic valueError

Tags: python, curve-fitting, valueerror

I'm using `minuit` to fit a simple curve but for some reason I get the

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous

Use `a.any()` or `a.all()`.

I don't understand were this comes from. I've tried doing something similar before and it has worked, all that I've changed is the functions so this is error is strange and I don't understand it.

```
import numpy as np
from iminuit import Minuit

#some constants
hc = 197.3269788
mssph = 685.78 
#some data and errors to fit
muds = np.array([ 
    81.96100485,  64.96427609,  38.15520137,  45.75992993,
    27.38344029,  23.41742996,  18.73586921,  18.07486749,
     9.20589292,   4.83878931,  72.17070899,  71.08083681,
    39.57647386,  31.63373626,  30.65363538,  26.50584842,
    19.33150992,  13.45482499,   3.86943831,  68.76598171,
    66.7933219 ,  38.86139831,  38.61246743,  38.6500419 ,
    16.62670414,  16.24156579,   9.16347451,  52.48804692,
    51.95712296,  23.86333781,  23.81815279,  12.44282442
    ]) #xdata
Fr = np.array([ 
    127.31527434,  122.72790265,  110.26449558,  112.75717699,
    104.81830088,  104.35746903,  101.32016814,  100.54513274,
     96.87942478,   92.98330088,  124.9736053 ,  122.52414305,
    112.47114172,  108.74591788,  107.34258013,  108.00597616,
    102.18850331,  100.04522384,   91.47210596,  128.18641113,
    122.15516847,  108.23229985,  109.85263369,  107.69218856,
     99.14042658,   98.0902102 ,   99.1104204 ,  112.47678261,
    110.39126087,   98.373     ,   98.97391304,   95.01495652
    ])#ydata
Zsrgi = np.array([1.47, 1.5, 1.54, 1.58])

dzs = np.array([ 3.60555128,  3.60555128,  4.24264069,  1.41421356])
Za = np.array([ 0.9468,  0.9632,  0.9707,  0.9756])

Zaey = np.array([56.0, 53.0, 35.0, 15.0])

dmfel = np.array([ 
     2743.82452989,  1388.6310737 ,   689.77566743,   652.7213305 ,
     348.31861265,   309.31427565,   134.12993165,   157.95193019,
      60.83965035,    19.80905202,  3482.5565895 ,  3378.1685061 ,
     949.07161448,   570.68604168,   492.42222648,   801.32561084,
     362.30696375,   152.61749342,    26.39235787,  2733.32712033,
    2329.20044751,   788.45797536,   754.06472854,  1098.9552043 ,
     279.63806125,   213.46692781,   169.87677303,  2181.08350448,
    2018.45039786,   696.73902333,   763.51325268,   416.74304481
    ])
af = np.array([ 
    0.0575465 ,  0.05547301,  0.04983955,  0.05096624,  0.04737787,
    0.04716958,  0.04579672,  0.0454464 ,  0.0437895 ,  0.04202845,
    0.04717754,  0.04625286,  0.04245786,  0.04105158,  0.04052182,
    0.04077226,  0.03857616,  0.03776707,  0.03453072,  0.0414683 ,
    0.0395172 ,  0.03501315,  0.03553733,  0.03483842,  0.03207193,
    0.03173218,  0.03206222,  0.03104359,  0.03046799,  0.02715095,
    0.0273168 ,  0.02622413
    ])
afe = np.array([ 
    0.00039571,  0.00046823,  0.00034898,  0.00071523,  0.00052648,
    0.00051809,  0.00072373,  0.00059257,  0.00054912,  0.00065308,
    0.000283  ,  0.00028516,  0.00031909,  0.0003537 ,  0.00035294,
    0.0002573 ,  0.00034244,  0.00034139,  0.00055726,  0.00038002,
    0.00044435,  0.00050214,  0.00052077,  0.00037143,  0.00036278,
    0.00045654,  0.00039068,  0.00025011,  0.00024068,  0.00031897,
    0.00037707,  0.0003581
    ])
amssr = np.array([ 
        0.35006,  0.34592,  0.33967,  0.3175 ,  0.31341,  0.34965,
        0.33393,  0.31033,  0.30807,  0.32813,  0.29895,  0.26546,
        0.29559,  0.29298,  0.26026,  0.29264,  0.29094,  0.29074,
        0.25928,  0.3888 ,  0.23213,  0.23284,  0.22768,  0.20825,
        0.22591,  0.20437,  0.22353,  0.2036 ,  0.18987,  0.20088,
        0.18743,  0.18801
        ])
amudr = np.array([
    0.01737619,  0.01377279,  0.00808912,  0.00970136,  0.00580544,
    0.00496463,  0.00397211,  0.00383197,  0.0019517 ,  0.00102585,
    0.01227267,  0.01208733,  0.00673   ,  0.00537933,  0.00521267,
    0.00450733,  0.00328733,  0.002288  ,  0.000658  ,  0.00950714,
    0.00923442,  0.00537273,  0.00533831,  0.00534351,  0.0022987 ,
    0.00224545,  0.00126688,  0.00588165,  0.00582215,  0.00267405,
    0.00266899,  0.0013943
    ])
amudre = np.array([
     8.75479519e-04,   7.34296720e-04,   4.51927448e-04,
     5.98343236e-04,   3.81187530e-04,   3.18993055e-04,
     4.05218892e-04,   3.28835732e-04,   2.14302222e-04,
     1.80198850e-04,   6.27776371e-04,   6.18193827e-04,
     3.56742512e-04,   3.04857443e-04,   3.08046099e-04,
     2.32852126e-04,   1.84120801e-04,   1.62566426e-04,
     7.02801597e-05,   5.87470469e-04,   5.70265978e-04,
     3.42904960e-04,   3.42757519e-04,   3.31231953e-04,
     1.52175013e-04,   1.61067797e-04,   8.21035930e-05,
     1.40038557e-04,   1.42199518e-04,   7.54950814e-05,
     7.13899224e-05,   3.64415759e-05
     ])


a = np.array([ 0.0904,  0.0755,  0.0647,  0.0552])

B = 2.61
Fc = 92.8
#functions to fit
def Fpapper(X,s,pp,k,l1,B=2.61,Fc=92.8,mu=770,Za=0.9468):
    temp1 = (2*B*X)/(4*pi*Fc)**2
    return Fc*pp*(1+k*s)*(1+l1*temp1)
def Bpapper(X,s,fa,pp,y1,y1s,l2,B=2.61,Fc=92.8,mu=770,Za=0.9468):
    temp1 = (2*B*X)/(4*pi*Fc)**2
    return pp*(1-fa**2*y1+y1s*s)*B*(1-l2)

#parameters initial values and errors
paramfelp=np.array([  1.01980390e-03,   1.14017543e-03,   1.14017543e-03,
     8.06225775e-04,   4.93659802e-04,   6.41248782e-04,
     4.57055795e-04,   9.40212742e-04,   9.00499861e-04,
     7.40270221e-04,   9.39840412e-04,   6.82641927e-04,
     8.63712915e-04,   8.39344983e-04,   4.66904701e-04,
     4.31740663e-04,   5.75673519e-04,   5.99082632e-04,
     6.49384324e-04,   5.02195181e-04,   8.20000000e-04,
     9.05207159e-04,   1.06901824e-03,   7.32461603e-04,
     7.50066664e-04,   9.83259884e-04,   1.19339851e-03,
     6.22896460e-04,   8.12157620e-04,   5.88727441e-04,
     5.20384473e-04,   5.53263048e-04,   5.31601354e-04,
     8.80511215e-04,   1.05233075e-03,   5.32353266e-04,
     1.30000000e-03,   1.30000000e-03,   1.80000000e-03,
     2.00000000e-04,   5.60000000e-03,   5.30000000e-03,
     3.50000000e-03,   1.50000000e-03,   1.00000000e+00,
     1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,
     1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,
     1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,
     1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,
     1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,
     1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,
     1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,
     1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,
     1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,
     1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,
     1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e-08,   1.00000000e-01,
     1.00000000e-03,   1.00000000e-05,   2.00000000e-03,
     4.00000000e-01,   5.00000000e-01]) #parameters error

parametersp=np.array([  9.04000000e-02,   7.55000000e-02,   6.47000000e-02,
     5.52000000e-02,   7.64118166e+02,   7.55081289e+02,
     7.41438660e+02,   6.93045528e+02,   6.84117792e+02,
     7.63223209e+02,   7.28909270e+02,   6.77394705e+02,
     6.72461531e+02,   7.16248911e+02,   7.81336428e+02,
     6.93806885e+02,   7.72554724e+02,   7.65733222e+02,
     6.80216152e+02,   7.64844597e+02,   7.60401473e+02,
     7.59878753e+02,   6.77654822e+02,   1.18579180e+03,
     7.07967722e+02,   7.10133134e+02,   6.94395773e+02,
     6.35136682e+02,   6.88997493e+02,   6.23303163e+02,
     6.81738788e+02,   7.27821973e+02,   6.78740461e+02,
     7.18098614e+02,   6.70018037e+02,   6.72091400e+02,
     6.80272109e-01,   6.66666667e-01,   6.49350649e-01,
     6.32911392e-01,   9.46800000e-01,   9.63200000e-01,
     9.70700000e-01,   9.75600000e-01,   8.19610049e+01,
     6.49642761e+01,   3.81552014e+01,   4.57599299e+01,
     2.73834403e+01,   2.34174300e+01,   1.87358692e+01,
     1.80748675e+01,   9.20589292e+00,   4.83878931e+00,
     7.21707090e+01,   7.10808368e+01,   3.95764739e+01,
     3.16337363e+01,   3.06536354e+01,   2.65058484e+01,
     1.93315099e+01,   1.34548250e+01,   3.86943831e+00,
     6.87659817e+01,   6.67933219e+01,   3.88613983e+01,
     3.86124674e+01,   3.86500419e+01,   1.66267041e+01,
     1.62415658e+01,   9.16347451e+00,   5.24880469e+01,
     5.19571230e+01,   2.38633378e+01,   2.38181528e+01,
     1.24428244e+01,   3.23442596e-07,   1.42713877e+01,
     9.00000000e-02,   1.12143829e-04,   9.00000000e-02,
     3.70000000e+00,   4.00000000e+00]) #parameters initial value

 #chisquare
def chiworkp(paras):
    B=2.61
    Fc=92.8
    hc=197.3269788
    mu=770
    betalat=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3]
    #chia=sum(((paras[0:4]-a)/(ast*10**(-4)))**2)+sum(((paras[4:36]*(paras[0:4][betalat])/hc-amssr)/(mse))**2)
    chiz=sum(((paras[36:40]-1/Zsrgi)/(dzs*10**(-2)))**2)+sum(((paras[40:44]-Za)/(Zaey*10**(-4)))**2)
    chiamd=sum(((amudr-(1+paras[77:78]*paras[0:4][betalat]**2)*paras[0:4][betalat]*paras[44:76]*paras[36:40][betalat]/hc)/amudre)**2)
    chiaf=sum(((af-Fpapper(paras[44:76],paras[4:36]**2-mssph**2,paras[0:4][betalat]/paras[40:44][betalat],paras[76:77],paras[77:78])/hc)/afe)**2)
    chiaB=sum((((ampir**2/(2*amudr))-Bpapper(paras[44:76],paras[4:36]**2-mssph**2,paras[0:4][betalat],paras[0:4][betalat]/paras[36:40][betalat],paras[77:78],paras[80:81])/hc)/Bfel)**2)
    return chia+chiz+chiamd+chiaf+chiaB

#minuit part
mc=minuit.Minuit(chiworkp,parametersp[:],paramfelp[:],errordef=1)

fminc, paramc = mc.migrad()

print(mc.values)
```

Comment: I appreciate your enthusiasm on this, but this big bunch of hard-to-read code makes it difficult to help. Try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). While doing so, you may already solve the problem yourself. In short: boil it down you definitively woun't need 30 parameters to reproduce the error.

Comment: Apart from this, try to post the full trace back, so one can see where the error comes up. This error normally appears if an array or list is passed to an `if` statement.. As there are non in your code, it might be in the `Minuit` wrapper